# Wordpress plugin that automates/streamlines finding and inserting post images

Tags: wordpress, flickr

I'm looking for a way to insert royalty (or otherwise) free photos quickly into the posts I write in Wordpress. (This image would serve as the primary image for that post, if it makes any difference.)

- Ideally there would be an "insert image" type of dialog that would have a search field.
- Submitting that search form with some keywords, there would be a list of thumbnails of images related to the search query.
- Image suggestions could come from sites like sxc.hu, flickr.com or everystockphoto.com, showing only images that are licensed for free use (optionally photos that are not licensed for commercial use could be filtered out).
- From this list I could then choose the most appropriate photo for the post.
- This plugin could also insert an attribution text for the image automatically.

That is, ideally. Naturally I'm ready to compromise. Then again, there might be even better solutions that have even smoother, quicker way of accomplishing post image automation.

I'd prefer a free plugin but paid one will do as well. Or several plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Zemanta](http://www.zemanta.com/). I think it handles everything you want, and it updates automagically based on the contents of your post.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the link! Unfortunately Zemanta does not seem to handle foreign texts as usefully as English ones. Majority of my content would be in a globally marginal language, Finnish. (From Zemanta FAQ: "Right now we only support English, but if you blog in other languages and mention trademarks, universal words, and buzzwords Zemanta might still be useful.")

Comment: Zemanta would've been perfect, so I'll accept the answer as it covers pretty much everything I posted in my question.

For people who have similar needs as I do: I'll probably use [insights](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/insights/) and [auto post thumbnail](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-post-thumbnail/) plugins. (iFlickr seemed to be working fairly well, too, but last update was years ago.)